# How to rewrite url in address bar without changing the actual URL?

Tags: webserver, apache-http-server, hosting, htaccess

I am facing SEO problem with my website cause my URLs are with `index.php`

For an example when I try to upload a file the URL is like this:

```
http://niresh12495.com/index.php?app=downloads
```

And when I try to upload an image the URL is this on the address bar:

```
http://niresh12495.com/index.php?app=upload
```

Is it possible to fake URL in the address bar the real address should be hidden

I need the URLs as follows:

- For the first example: `http://niresh12495.com/app/downloads`
- For the second example: `http://niresh12495.com/app/upload`

There is also another problem that `http://niresh12495.com/index.php` is not redirected to `http://niresh12495.com/`

I tried to hide `index.php` but in some case there is a trailing question mark after URL

Once I fixed the URL completely but the problem was when I tried to post a topic the url was redirected to `niresh12495.com/index.php?` then to the home page `niresh12495.com`.

It looks like arguments are passing through `index.php`? I'm not completely sure of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?app=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /app/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^app/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?app=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: not working if index.php is removed i can't even login is it possible to redirect just index.php (not rewrite) to root